# What is this fur on the outer leaves on my Peperomia angulata?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

There is white fur on some outer leaves of my peperomia angulata. Is this normal or should I be worried?

[image]

New images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: does it come off when you rub it?  do you see other white fluffy areas on the underside of the leaves?

Comment: I can rub it up and there is a bit fluffy stuff under the leaves too.

Comment: lets get a close up of who or what is under the leaf please

Comment: It's hard to see. I don't think I can get a good picture. It's not really visible on the underside.

Comment: ok, no risk, maximum benefit solution.  If this leaf is the only one with the fuzz remove it and dispose in the garbage. If it has mealy bug, problem solved!  If not, then it's only a leaf

Comment: is it maybe some fertilisation thing?

Comment: Unlikely, more closeup pictures please

Comment: I agree with @kevinsky that no harm can come from taking off that one leaf. Since it's hard to get a picture of the underneath while it's on the plant, feel free to pick it off. Put it upside down on a piece of paper on a table, and you should be able to get a nice, close picture. That's what I do!

Comment: Added some images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- no signs of mealybug which looks like white cottony tufts.
- no signs of a nutrient deficiency such as yellow leaf tissue and green veins
- there are no dead or necrotic areas that would indicate a virus/fungus/bacteria

I don't see anything to worry about.  If you want to be sure remove the leaves that have this.